# How to get the usage record of USB device on Linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, usb-drive

I want to write a linux inspection tool to check the usb device usage records on a certain machine. Parsing the dmesg method can obtain the usb usage record from the system startup to the present, and does not use dmesg -c to clear the dmesg information. So the point of the question is whether there is a place on the Linux system that records all USB usage records in the system, just like the Windows system writes this in the registry.

Comment: Are you looking for just what devices are plugged in at the moment, or the history of all devices that have ever been plugged in?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't seem to make it clear. I want to get the history of all usb devices that have ever been plugged in.

Comment: Write a udev rule for that. Or simple enable log for the service itself.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But this software is not designed to run all the time and cannot monitor by udev in real time, so I want to know if there are any files or other things on the linux system that record the history of the usb device.@0andriy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux doesn't natively provide this functionality.  It isn't seen as an intrinsically important feature to have, and as mentioned, it can be done easily with a `udev` rule for those who want it.  It's generally assumed that anyone with physical access to the machine can read any unencrypted data on it and execute arbitrary code on it if it's running, so logging USB devices isn't really an effective security measure.

If you want to see the recent history, you can check the kernel log (often `/var/log/kern.log`) to read the recent and older entries that the kernel has output when a USB device has been inserted.  Do note that these are rotated periodically, so they won't provide the entire history of the system.

Comment: OK, I agree with you.